# If bottom of div is visible jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help me out here, if bottom of div or full div is visible then i want to scroll to down of next div. Here the code i have tried out,

Mathematically,

```
var top = $("#myDiv").offset().top;
//top = 1863
var divHeight = $("#myDiv").height();
//divHeight = 571
var total = top + divHeight;
//total = 2434
if($('#myDiv').css('height',total).visible(true))
  {
   alert('hi');
   // I need to alert only if the full div is visible not some part of div
  }
else
{
//if height of myDiv is larger window height (my screen height 640 pixels)
}
```

If all this part of html(from top to divHeight) or bottom of page(here total value) is visible then i need to scroll to next div.
Please note :- the code inside if conditional statement is not correct, i think you got some idea from that.

Comment: 'if loop'? you mean 'if statement'?

Comment: sorry conditional statement, sorry by mistake

Comment: `visible(true)` want do anything instead use `$(element).is(":visible")`

Comment: i know this, it will display if the div is visible. I need to alert only if the full div is visible not some part of div

Answer (score 0):

Given `element` the jQuery object you want to check, `element` is fully visible if it is [shown](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and all of the 4 sides of its layout box fall within the window viewport.

***Caution:*** the following solution assumes that there are no element with scrollable overflow between `element` and the document root, otherwise the calculation becomes way more complicated.

```
function isFullyVisible(element) {
    var offset = element.offset();
    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    var scrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();

    return element.is(":visible") && // shown
        offset.top >= scrollTop && // top
        offset.left >= scrollLeft && // left
        offset.top + element.outerHeight() <= scrollTop + $(window).height() && // bottom
        offset.left + element.outerWidth() <= scrollLeft + $(window).width(); // right
}
```

If you don't care of sides, you can keep only the corresponding sub-expression.