# How to check if lowest part of div is visible in viewport?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the formula to check if the lowest part of the div is visible in the viewport?
It doesn't matter upper half is visible or gets hidden while scrolling the div

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to recognise if something is on screen. If you make a placeholder  and magnetise it to the bottom of a parent div then you can make it possible.

But if you don't want to use IntersectionObserver  API you can try  getBoundingClientRect() + window.innerHeight like shown below:

```js
const targetEl = document.querySelector('#target');
const windowsHeight = window.innerHeight;

// I heartily recommend to use some kind of throttling (lo-dash.throttle) here to reduce amount of callback executions
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const bottom = targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
  
  if (windowsHeight > bottom) {
    console.log('bottom is visible');
  } else {
    console.log('bottom is hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
/* All css are just for the demo, you only need a JS code */
body {
  padding: 300px 20px;
}

#target {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  content here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but due to some reason, I don't want to use intersection api

Comment: Okay. let me think what can be a solution

Comment: @Deepika What is task? Describe why do you need this. Probably you don't need this :)

Comment: if something can be possible with element.getBoundingClientRect and window heights...that would be much helpful

Comment: I folowed up this (after converting jquery to react.js)-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48461869/if-bottom-of-div-is-visible-jquery but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Deepika I changed my answer to use getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: @Deepika Does it work for you as expected?

Comment: No @Max even after scrolling a little bit, this functionality returns true

Comment: @cssyphus Thanks for the advices. They are helpful

Comment: @Deepika In your code or in my snippet?